# gatsby-plugin-preact is not working with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap, preact, gatsby-plugin

I integrated react-bootstrap in my gatsby project but it is not working with gatsby-plugin-preact  plugin.
If I comment out that line in gatsby-config file then the project develop successfully else it's failing with below screenshot detail.
Any idea or help.
Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the plugin is missing an alias for `react/jsx-runtime`. You'll want to open this issue on the plugin, probably link to the docs: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-in-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `null` loader to `react-boostrap` webpacks bundling (in your `gatsby-node.js`)?

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, getConfig }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-boostrap/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
}
```

This will bypass the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) and should fix the `react/jsx-runtime dependency` .

You can also try aliasing the Preact to force webpack to get Preact instead of React:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "react": "preact/compat",
        "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
        "react-dom": "preact/compat",
        "react/jsx-runtime": "preact/jsx-runtime"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

*Source: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started/#aliasing-react-to-preact and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70920270/5585371*

Comment: nope it's still failing

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue. For me, the issue was with aliasing react to preact.

I did some reading from the [Official Docs at Preact](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-react-to-preact) and this helpful blog post about [aliasing in Gatsby](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-set-up-import-aliases-for-gatsby-32398ae67e7f).

I ended up doing the following to fix my issue.

In `gatsby-node.js` add the following:

```js
const path = require("path")
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "react": "preact/compat",
        "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
        "react-dom": "preact/compat",
        "react/jsx-runtime": "preact/jsx-runtime"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Obviously, make sure all your preact and gastby-plugin-preact libraries are up to date before doing this, etc.

I hope that you, or someone else, in the same boat finds this helpful!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed, made a PR to correct it in Gatsby. It's not an issue in your setup, but upstream.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/34666